# jQuery resizable containment - leaves a space on right

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-resizable

I have one div containing an image and a translucent window over it that is draggable and resizable. I am using the parent div as the containment parameter for the respective jQuery UI interactions. But when I resize the window, I can only resize it to 10px less than the parent width. No matter which image I use. No issues resizing to the full height. No issues dragging to the far right or bottom.
Here is the code (Try it here - [JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Apeksha82/soL56ww3/1/))

HTML:

```
<div id="container">
  <div id="navi">
    <img src="http://www.mountainevolution.com/Cento%20Fonti/images/dscn7587.jpg" />
  </div>
  <div id="infoi">
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#container {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  position: relative;
}

#infoi {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  background-color: lightblue;
  border: solid 1px navy;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  opacity: 0.5;
}

#navi {
  padding: 0px;
  position: absolute; 
}

#navi img {
  display: block;  
}
```

JS:

```
$("#infoi").draggable({
  containment: "#navi"
});
$("#infoi").resizable({
  containment: "#navi"
});
```

I have played around with margins and padding, and also looked at other questions on StackOverflow. None of them are similar to mine. There are some questions on problems with using resizable and draggable together. In my case, removing draggable does not affect the issue, so I don't think it is a problem with using them together.

Comment: I have the same problem. Did you find any solution?

Comment: @Cr1xus Not yet (Project priority shifted). Will update when I get back to this